# How to use android emulator with delphi Alexandria

Tags: delphi, android-emulator, android-13

With the new android 13 there is now some new modifications regarding the permissions needed to receive notifications (arrgh!). Instead of buying all the time a new phone, I'm curious if there is a way to launch a simulator to test the new features? does someone know how I can run an emulator with android 13 so that I can try my app (made with delphi) if it's work well on android 13? I not necessary need to debugging feature, I only need to be able to install my app in it and run it. If possible I would like to avoid to install android studio

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not totally mistaken, all last versions  of suitable alternatives (Bluestacks, Genymotion, Xamarin Studio, ...) to Android Studio's emulator have release dates prior to the release date of Android 13.

So I fear you can't avoid Android Studio for now considering an Android 13 emulator, or you have to target a lower Android version if possible (as usually recommended).

And yes -- argh :-D Permission changes are always fun.

Comment: My answer is only valid (at least I think so) for GUI Emulators, as I have completely forgotten about Android Virtual Devices (AVD) via CLI. Must refresh my knowledge on that.